# When supply fan VFD starts up it causes communication problems for my energy management controller

Tags: communication, control-system, vfd

We have an energy management system that controls the air handlers for a building. I have one unit that when the supply fan VFD starts up it cause the unit controller to start having communication issue. The controller starts to reconfigure and drags down all the other controllers. The controller is fine, we have replaced it with a new one just to make sure. It sounds like its electrical noise causing the issue. Any ideas on how I can correct the problem?

Thanks in advance,

Henry

Comment: Please post a schematic of how things are wired together - use black boxes, but make sure the way you draw the wires reflects how they are laid out, ie close wires may crosstalk. You could also post a picture of the installation. There are so many possible causes that more info is needed. A link on the VFD and "energy management system" and "controller" and "unit" docs would also help...

Answer (score 2):

Start with the VFD manual. Check to see that all of the wiring conforms to the manufacturer's recommendations. There are usually recommendations to have input power wiring, motor wiring and VFD start\stop, speed command etc. wiring in different conduits. Any signal wiring needs to be separate from relay wiring. The VFD enclosure and motor should be grounded to earth. It is best to run the protective earth ground conductors to the service entrance ground. Check to make sure that the "unit controller" wiring is well separated from the VFD wiring. If the installation is as it should be, contact the VFD supplier for recommendations. You may need a noise filter at the VFD power input.